# WinCE 6.0 9x skin, odd behavior

Tags: windows-ce, skins

I have a problem when I disable the item "Windows XP-like Sample Skin" on
my WinCE 6 BSP catalog. The buttons, check boxes and other
controls are drawn transparent or with a strange look. Like the activesync
dialog in the imagen shown at the link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWjG5.jpg

In the picture, as the background is black, the buttons and the upper bar seems to be black to, but actually they are transparent.

However if I left the XP skin selected, it works fine.

I was wonder if anyone have the same problem or is there a workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to do a clean sysgen of your OSDesign.
You can find that command in the build menu.
Be careful, I said "clean sysgen" and not build and sysgen!